# C++ and Pthread extend class

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I must to use PThread in c++

Is possible to implement a my Class (Worker) that extend a thread?
reimplement ::run() etc..

How can I make it?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, `pthreads` are not a class but a framework of functions, structs,... YOu can't extend anything there!

Comment: You can "extend them", C++ picks up where C left off. you create a primitive class that holds the thread id and has a run function accepting a functor. Boom something you can extend.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel [c++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) and [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread.html) have a thread class.